# Is there a way to view weblogic logs within eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, logging, weblogic

We deployed a project with weblogic, and logging isn't too fun.

Is there a way for custom logs and/or weblogic logs to be seen within the Console of eclipse? I know there is a redirect option for output within the weblogic console, but is there a way to simply *copy* the logs so I can see them within eclipse as well?

If not, is there a way to see only custom logs within eclipse? (ex: manually writing `LOG.debug("This is a test error and here is the stacktrace: " + e.printStackTrace());`, and being able to see that within eclipse, rather than having to view it somewhere else)?

Thanks,